# Why does %20 become %2520 when I use a redirected url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, https

### This works as expected - it returns one record:

```
https://terraref.ncsa.illinois.edu/bety/api/v1/search.json?sitename=~Season%204&limit=1
```

### this does not

when I use the base url terraref.org rather than terraref.ncsa.illinois.edu:

```
https://terraref.org/bety/api/v1/search.json?sitename=~Season%204&limit=1
```

because in this second case the `%` is replaced by `%25` and the query term is then not found.

### Questions

- How can I fix it?
- Why has this appeared in the last few months and

#### Update

you can see question history for the red herring related to the R packages I was using
thanks to the comments, I've narrowed down the issue, I think

I've included tags ruby-on-rails and nginx because these are the tools that the api and server are using.

Comment: urlencoding maybe?

Comment: @cory not sure if this is what you mean, but `URLencode('Foo%20Bar')` returns `Foo%20Bar`

Comment: Verify that it is not a server issue and/or misconfigured server redirect as it was in this case https://stackoverflow.com/a/59779232/2864740 - in that case the issue was reproducible without r/httr.

Comment: It seems like that is what is happening... twice. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Comment: %20 is code for space, %25 is code for %

Comment: @user2864740 I have done; removing 25 from the string makes it work as expected

Comment: So, if instead of passing `"Test 1"`, you pass `URLencode("Test 1")`... does it work?

Comment: @cory no it doesn’t :-(

Comment: cant reproduce the error in your MRE on R 3.6.2. Is it `utils:::modifyList` you are using? because i cant see that the function calls any other function than itself. My best guess is also the url encoding as mentioned in the first two comments: Check `URLencode("Foo%20Bar", reserved = TRUE, repeated = TRUE)` and `URLencode("Foo%20Bar", reserved = TRUE, repeated = FALSE)`. So one hypothesis would be that the `repeated` parameter was changed in a function call or at least passed through over `...`,...but i cant see where your MRE code comes to an encoding function,...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779173/httr-replaces-with-25-in-url-sometimes?rq=1. But as you seem to use https, probably not the issue for you. But maybe of interest for future googlers who arrive here =).

Comment: *the function modifyList* IS NOT  *replacing %20 with %2520* on my system (R 3.6.3).

Comment: @sindri_baldur I can confirm that the error in my MRE is not working on R 3.6.1 as well. I'll update the question

Comment: As @cory mentioned % = %25, have you tried escaping the %? so passing foo\%20bar instead of foo%20bar

Answer (score 4):

Somehow, you are encoding the value for `sitename` 2 times. In this example the decoded value is `Season 4` when you encode first time `Season%204`and doing it the second time `%20Season%25204`.

Investigate the code to verify whether value for `sitename` already encoded and you doing it again.

Answer (score 4):

Check Chrome DevTools to debug the problem.

[image]

Your call is being redirected with the following query parameters.

```
sitename: ~Season 4
limit: 1
```

If you choose the encoded view, you'll see the culprit.

[image]

So, as one might expect, it's just as simple as double url encoding.

If you need to use `terraref.org` as a base url, replace space with a plus.

```
https://terraref.org/bety/api/v1/search.json?sitename=~Season+4&limit=1
```

Comment: @David LeBauer If you are interested in more justification about space/plus solution, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948396/3262990) amazing answer.